# Algorithm to vertically flip a bitmap in a byte array

Tags: c#, android, algorithm, image-processing, xamarin.android

I am writing a class for printing bitmaps to a portable bluetooth printer in Android via Mono For Android. My class is used to obtain the pixel data from the stream so that is can be sent to the printer in the correct format. Right now the class is simple, it just reads the height, width, and bits per pixel.

Using the offset it reads and returns the pixel data to the printer. Right now I am just working with 1 bit per pixel black and white images. The bitmaps I am working with are in Windows format.

Here is the original image:

[image: Original Image (Sent as Bitmap)]

[image: Result of printing and initial attempt at flip]

Here is the result of printing, the first image is without any transformation. And the second one is the result of modifying the BitArray with the following code:

```
        BitArray bits = new BitArray(returnBytes);
        BitArray flippedBits = new BitArray(bits);

        for (int i = 0, j = bits.Length - 1; i < bits.Length; i++, j--)
        {
            flippedBits[i] = bits[j];
        }
```

My Question is:

How do I flip the image vertically when I am working with a byte array. I am having trouble finding the algorithm for doing this, all examples seem to suggest using established graphics libraries which I cannot use.

Edit:

My Bitmap is saved in a 1 dimensional array, with the first rows bytes, then the second, third, etc.

Comment: Are you looking an algo to swap numbers in the matrix, the pixels of the image, so the image is rotated? What do you mean by `flip`

Comment: @Adrian Yes, I need to modify the array so that the image is printed in the proper orientation. I am looking for the algorithm that would perform the "flip vertical" command in photoshop or other paint programs.

Comment: Is the format so that the bit array contains `width*height*bits_per_pixel` bits? And if so, is it organised in the form `[first_row|second_row|...]`?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, the bit array contains the firstrow, then second row etc. It will always be in 1 bit per pixel format.

Comment: @dmck, any chance you could share a little bit of how you did this?  More specifically, setting up your pixels to a proper format for your printer?  I'm really stuck there.

Comment: @dispake What time of printer are you writing to? If you have a open question post the link and I will do my best to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(returnBytes);
BitArray flippedBits = new BitArray(bits);

for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length; i += width) {
    for (int j = 0, k = width - 1; j < width; ++j, --k) {
        flippedBits[i + j] = bits[i + k];
    }
}
```

If you need to mirror picture upside-down, use this code:

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(returnBytes);
BitArray flippedBits = new BitArray(bits);

for (int i = 0, j = bits.Length - width; i < bits.Length; i += width, j -= width) {
    for (int k = 0; k < width; ++k) {
        flippedBits[i + k] = bits[j + k];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the format with `width*height` bits in row order, you just need to view the bit array as a two-dimensional array.

```
for(int row = 0; row < height; ++row) {
    for(int column = 0; column < width; ++column) {
        flippedBits[row*width + column] = bits[row*width + (width-1 - column)];
    }
}
```

It would be a bit more complicated if there were more than one bit per pixel.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two loops, the first to iterate over all the rows and the second to iterate the pixels inside each row.

```
for (int y = 0;  y < height;  y++)
{
    int row_start = (width/8) * y;
    int flipped_row = (width/8) * (height-1 - y);
    for (int x = 0;  x < width/8;  x++)
    {
        flippedBits[flipped_row+x] = bits[row_start+x];
    }
}
```