# Return raw image bits in a BMP file

Tags: c#, .net, image, matlab

I have C# dll that I am using in Matlab to return the raw 8-bit grey scale bits that are stored in a BMP file. (Yes, I know Matlab can read the BMP, but this is a test, for a real system where the data will come from a video frame grabber).

Right now, the code below is returning 1078 bits of header information, that needs to be stripped, and it is also flipping the axis of the image (it comes out in mirror image). What is the best way to fix this (least lines, performance is not not a concern).

```
image = Image.FromFile(this.imagePath);
ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
data = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));
Frame f = new Frame(data);

public class Frame
{
    public byte[,] frameData = new byte[1024, 1024];

    public Frame(byte[] data)
    {
        Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, frameData, 0, 1024 * 1024 * sizeof(byte));
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want an answer in `C#` or `Matlab` ? At least for the second part (flipping back the image), Matlab could do that in one line.

Comment: I'm skeptical of the use of `ImageConverter` here. You can access the actual bitmap data directly, without the header, using other mechanisms, like the `LockBits()` method. If you are trying to pass a `byte[]` to Matlab and want help with that, you also need to be specific about the format you are trying to create. A `byte[]` presumably, but what else? Any specific pixel format? Does Matlab have specific rules for stride you need to follow? That sort of thing.

Comment: I was looking to do the work in C#, not matlab. I just wanted a raw byte array so  that Matlab can read it as an array of uint8. LockBits looks like it gets me around the header problem. Thanks

Comment: However, I don't see a way to go from BitMapData to bytes[].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(returnBytes);
BitArray flippedBits = new BitArray(bits);

for (int i = 0; i < bits.Length; i += width) {
    for (int j = 0, k = width - 1; j < width; ++j, --k) {
        flippedBits[i + j] = bits[i + k];
    }
}
```

If you need to mirror picture upside-down, use this code:

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(returnBytes);
BitArray flippedBits = new BitArray(bits);

for (int i = 0, j = bits.Length - width; i < bits.Length; i += width, j -= width) {
    for (int k = 0; k < width; ++k) {
        flippedBits[i + k] = bits[j + k];
    }
}
```

Source:
[Algorithm to vertically flip a bitmap in a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199866/algorithm-to-vertically-flip-a-bitmap-in-a-byte-array)

Comment: yea, I need the mirror, or as you say in matlab A' (transpose).